# Using enums in method arguments in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, enums

I have a header file `ApiManager.h` in which I define an enum:

```
typedef enum ApiEndpoint {
    // some values
} ApiEndpoint;
```

In that file, I have a method that takes one of these values as an argument:

```
- (NSString *) getPathForEndpoint: (ApiEndpoint) endpoint;
```

And that seems to be fine for XCode. In another file, however, `ApiManagerDelegate.h`, I have the following definitions:

```
- (void) requestToEndpoint: (ApiEndpoint) endpoint succeeded: (id) responseObject;
- (void) requestToEndpoint: (ApiEndpoint) endpoint failed: (NSError *) error;
```

And XCode flags both of the `ApiEndpoint` arguments with the error `expected a type`. I have imported `ApiManager.h` so `ApiEndpoint` does show up in the completions list, but for some reason XCode isn't recognising it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd suggest to use the typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UITableViewCellStyle) macro to define your enum.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like cyclic dependencies were the problem, as pointed out by @trojanfoe who has mysteriously deleted his answer.

Moving the `typedef` to a separate file `ApiEndpoint.h` solved the issue.